# inserting data into database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "" , "prosports1");
if(!isset($con)) {
die("Connection failed !!!");
}
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$query = "INSERT INTO review VALUES 
    ('','$name','$email','$contact','$subject','$message')";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(isset($res)) {
//header("Location: homepage.php");
}
}
?>
```

i have used this code to insert the data to database[phpmyadmin]
but it's not working
what to do

Comment: please reply as soon as possible

Comment: How about your php error.log file ? What `mysqli_error` function return ?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example code for `POST` method. It worked for me. Follow the pattern, there isn't much of any change from your code.

```
<form action="new.php" method="post">
ID:<input type="text" name="id">
Name:<input type="text" name="name">
age:<input type="text" name="age">
place:<input type="text" name="city">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password","db_name");
$sql = "INSERT INTO employee VALUES ('$_POST[id]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[city]')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "Data Inserted<br>";
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Don't forget to change the action page and essential details. Cheers.

Comment: Great. Check your code again, 'if(isset($_POST['send']))'. The 'send' might be 'submit'. That can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT into TABLE (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record Successfully<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write query in this way.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO review (column1 , column2 , column3 , column4 , column5 , column6) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$contact','$subject','$message')";
if(isset($res)) {
//header("Location: homepage.php");
}
```

replace column names with your table attributes.